# What is this shape that looks like a rectangle with rounded ends called?

Tags: shapes, terminology

[image: A rounded rectangle but with full radius.]

This cannot be a rounded rectangle because those are not fully or "perfectly" rounded at the two ends. This is more like an elongated circle? A flat cylinder?

I searched a lot, but among all guides or pictures that identify and name different shapes, I couldn't get this particular shape. The closest I could get was a stretched ellipse.

There are only two processes to get this shape as far as I know: the first one is making a long rectangle and making its corner radius exactly half of the height. The second one is putting two circles a distance apart and adding a rectangle between those. So, are these something like "perfect rounded rectangles" or "rectangular circles"?

Comment: I would call it "rounded stroke cap"

Comment: Yes, that seems like a good name. This is a stroke cap after all, while the stroke has rounded corners. But we specifically make this shape too, in general designs, using rounded rectangles and not strokes. This shape might be an important, big, and bold part of the layout. Calling it just a stroke cap won't be enough.

Comment: I see... In this case, I guess "Stadium shape" as suggested by @Danielillo might be more suitable.

Comment: Worth noting that I was completely wrong. I instantly thought "lozenge" but that's a diamond apparently! Who knew? Not me!

Comment: This was asked a long time ago on math.stackexchange https://math.stackexchange.com/q/539262/29335

Comment: @rschwieb: interesting, but the Math.SE accepted answer beats around the bush about actually answering the question.

Comment: @smci I'm not saying the answers there make these unnecessary, I'm just linking up existing resources to each other to make both questions better. (You'll notice I linked this question to that one simultaneously.) It's also probably good to know a bunch of mathematicians came to all the same conclusions that appeared here, isn't it? Sorry about beating around the bush. I guess it takes a sense of humor to read some of my answers.

Comment: Ah, someone even pointed out a second math.se version below I was previously unaware of: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/5465/29335

Comment: @rschweib: can you just clean up [that answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/539274), already? You suggest a jumble of five different possibilities, while simultaneously arguing it probably doesn't have a name anyway. Since you already know the answer is 'stadium', your answer needs updating. Why not put the correct answer first, the alternatives after, and delete (or rephrase) the lengthy conjecturing that it doesn't have a name?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## Stadium Shape

As a geometric figure.

> A stadium is a geometric figure consisting of a rectangle with top and bottom lengths *a* whose ends are capped off with semicircles of radius *r*.

[image]

Sources [mathworld.wolfram.com/Stadium.html](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Stadium.html) / [mentalfloss.com](http://mentalfloss.com/article/54639/12-shapes-you-didnt-know-had-names#file-127022)

---

## Capsule Shape

Following @Rafael's answer, there are many results in Google as **Capsule Shape**

Comment: In the US I'm sure a lot of ppl think of a Baseball stadium.

Comment: Perhaps because of my primarily 3D design area of knowledge, I refer to this form and shape as a capsule - though that is most often applied to the 3D solid of similar form, it's also often used for the 2D silhouette of that same form.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capsule_(geometry)

Comment: I've seen it called a "racetrack" as well, same basic idea.

Comment: The generic stadium is also known as a racetrack (Which can also be curved)

Answer (score 31):

While perhaps not the "technical" term for it.. I see it often called a **Pill Shape**.

Comment: This is the terminology Twitter's design team uses: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/badge/#pill-badges

Comment: I like this one too, although the bigger the major axis gets, the less appropriate it seems :)

Comment: [Pill](https://www.drugs.com/images/pills/mmx/t110927f/montelukast-sodium.jpg) shape, uh, sure.

Answer (score 6):

Obround is another alternative. See [this question on math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5465/what-is-the-proper-geometrical-name-for-a-horse-race-track) or the [wiktionary definition](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/obround).

Two out of Wikipedia's five [stadium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stadium_(geometry)) references use obround instead.

Answer (score 4):

For me, it is a rounded rectangle just because the tool I would use is a rectangle and I would round it.

On a 3D model, I would use a sphere and move some vertexes.

But for non-graphic designers, I would call it a "Pill shape" Probably Penicillin pill shape.

Answer (score 0):

A technical word for this kind of shape is Oblong.

See : https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/oblong

Comment: By [definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/oblong), an oblong is more general term, not describing shape of the corners. It might work in some communities but be confusing in general use.

Comment: @miroxlav the definition changes between UK and US English.

Comment: Quote:  "If you stretch a circle until it becomes an oval" you get an oval, an ellipse.

Comment: @PeteKirkham – it does, but which one exactly describes the above shape? I think neither.

Comment: Agree that oblong has very large meaning but it could be a word for this kind of shape. Also there is no specific word for every trapezoid maybe there is none for an elongated shape without perfectly rounded corner.

Answer (score 0):

*in addition to all the other options...*

**Sausage Body**

Also, **Discorectangle**

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Stadium.html