# Good name for object between squared and rounded

Tags: terminology, button

In the following image we have squared, rounded, lined and dashed objects. Each object is labeled with its name, but I have a situation between squared and rounded objects. What name would you use for this object?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps curved?

Comment: I guess it's still just "rounded", just with a smaller corner radius. The one you have named "rounded" just happens to have the same corner radius as half the height. Don't think there is a proper name, but we'll see.

Comment: In a advanced search, looking for files with SASS extension and with `btn--` prefixed in the class name, I found people, using for this case, `btn--curved`.

Comment: [On fillets and rounds](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-357499AE-7EF5-4228-8DE9-7FA6A8F11C27-htm.html).

Comment: The are those who call it.....a squircle.

Comment: The one on the far left is also slightly rounded.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Rounded corner** or just **Round Corner**. Adding the "corner", to me, means there's an apparent corner as opposed to the Pill shape.

As @Wolff points out in the comment above, both the pill shape and the shape preceding it are "rounded" shapes, merely the radius of the rounding varies. So.. I'd use a *more specific* name for what you've labeled as "rounded".

I'd probably change the list.

- `Squared` - `Rounded` - `Pill` - `Lined`- `Dashed`
  **or**
- `Squared` - `Rounded` - `Stadium` - `Lined`- `Dashed`
  **or**
- `Squared` - `Rounded` - `Oblong` - `Lined`- `Dashed`

Related: [What is this shape that looks like a rectangle with rounded ends called?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/117005/what-is-this-shape-that-looks-like-a-rectangle-with-rounded-ends-called)

Comment: Yes! Pill is a good name and have common use.

Comment: Since we are nitpicking here: How does "squared" make sense? Shouldn't it be "right-angled"? And the "squared" illustration in the question is actually also "rounded" a little bit I see.

Comment: @Wolff you can't see my *shrugggg*  Maybe  ---- `slightly hard cornered rectangle but still rounded just a little` ------ `slightly more round corner rectangle same as previous but with smoother corners` ------ `really rounded rectangle much more rounded than previous two rectangles` ----- `a hard, perpendicular, corner rectangle with only a stroke and no fill` -----  `a hard, perpendicular, corner rectangle with only a dashed stroke and no fill`------ ??? Would make for some interesting buttons  

Comment: @Scott, How did you get your hands on my unpublished "Concise Naming of Rectangular Objects and Their Corners"???

Comment: @Wolff ermm... I was reading *The Guide to Ridiculous Naming Conventions Used in Denmark.* -- Did *you* write that?? Nice.........

Comment: I'm not sure about your suggestion of "oblong" - that's too often a synonym for rectangle, i.e. hard-cornered.

Comment: @Wolff In common English use "square" or "squared" has two meanings - it can either mean a rectangle with all sides having equal length or a 90 degree angle/right angle (the second meaning is used all the time in craftsmanship such as carpentry, paper sculpting, origami, machining, manufacturing etc. It is common to say things like "make sure all your joints are square")

Comment: Squircle might be close but not a very common word, the Zune Music players back in the day referred to their button that was square this way but this is more of a rectangle, rounded rectangle might fit better after all!

Comment: @ChrisH See the related question link in this answer.... that's where Oblong came from.

Comment: @Scott the only mention of "oblong" at that link is a zero-vote answer, which links to a rather questionable dictionary definition.  Questionable for 2 reasons: It fails to match more well-known dictionaries (or at least, those that include anything with non-straight sides list it after a simple rectangle); none of its own examples unambiguously support this definition, in fact most support a definition as a simple rectangle.  That old question does support "stadium" and "pill"

Comment: ....well.. to me.. "official" is irrelevant. The important aspect is clarity for the user. Placing the word "oblong" on the pill shape would be clear and understood, even if there's no dictionary which "officially" defines the shape as "oblong".

Comment: "oblong" ?????? can you show any literature supporting this usage of that word. Its dictionary definition is different, its mathematical usage is different, its everyday usage is (as far as I am familiar with) different. I haven't seen any designers using "oblong" to describe a pill button either. I think the answer should evidence its usage in design contexts.

Comment: By definition "oblong" merely means wider than it is tall / longer than it is wide. Can you show me something which states an oblong shape can't have rounded corners? A "square" is *still* a "square" when its corners are rounded.... a "rectangle" is *still* a "rectangle" when its corners are rounded...

Comment: @RoguePlanetoid A squircle is a closed quadratic curve of continuous curvature, not a combination of straight lines and circular arcs with discontinuities in curvature.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it wasn't quite right after I said it good to have it confirmed!

Comment: While “stadium” is the correct term in geometry, few “stadiums” (at least in the US) actually have that shape, which means it’s unlikely to be understood correctly unless the site’s audience is largely geometers to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

I quite like "[cartouche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartouche)", as a single word. This is a good alternative to "stadium" or "pill" etc for the middle symbol, but I don't have the reputation to comment that!

Answer (score 2):

There is a certain class of shapes unifying the ellipse & the square, but its name isn't a common term or applicable to other generalizations. Piet Hein, who invented the Soma cube, also gave the name [superellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse) to a class of curves generalizing the ellipse which in the limit includes the square. It was described in Martin Gardner's Scientific American Mathematical Games column (written for the general reader). (The superellipse & its 3-D solid of revolution, the superegg, turn out to be deceivingly metastable; they tilt but return to upright when not pushed too far.)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have always known that shape as a 'Roundrect'.

Historical usage:
https://www.folklore.org/StoryView.py?story=Round_Rects_Are_Everywhere.txt

Reference:
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/roundrect

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion, in the style of Scott's answer, for these fairly long rectangular buttons (bold text is my new suggestions).:

Squared - rounded* - **round-ended** - **outline** - dashed

* (or round-cornered)

Reasoning:

- "Rounded-ended" is more immediately descriptive than "stadium" or even "pill" (real pills can even be circular).
- "Outline" fits your example where the fill matches the background; "lined" or "outline**d**" would also cover [image: Lined button with faint fill]

Comment: Pills can also be square, triangles, hexagons..etc. One need **not** be literal. "Pill" is **very** common jargon used to describe the shape in design circles.

Answer (score 0):

If I want to draw that shape in AutoCAD, I start with a rectangle and then fillet the corners. So by AutoCAD conventions, your shape is a filleted rectangle or a filleted box.

Answer (score 0):

How about 'Beveled'? thats what its called in blender (3d modelling program)

Comment: Bevel is usually a straight edge, like a chamfer, not a round one. It's just rounded.

Comment: Hi Riley, thanks for your answer. As stated by others, I think 'beveled' means something different, as evidenced by a quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=beveled&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZmtD93uvtAhV65eAKHYMyC_kQ_AUoAXoECAYQAw&biw=1667&bih=860&dpr=2.25).

Answer (score -2):

A mixture of words can be fun: Squounded

Comment: downvoters may be surprised to learn that [squircles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squircle) exist.

Comment: @CeeMcSharpface although squircles exist, squounded doesn't and it's a horrid word just to describe a rounded rectangle.

Comment: @Luciano That's a rather moist opinion.

Answer (score -4):

Maybe "Roundly Truncated"?

Comment: Hello This One, judging by the 4 downvotes, people are not liking your answer much. No worries, that's quite OK. Don't hesitate to keep contributing to the site.